# What is the use of Mono.fromCompletionStage with eager execution?

Tags: project-reactor

I am currently writing a wrapper around a library using `CompletableFuture` and I want to return a `Mono` instead.

```
public Mono<Void> delete(Message message) {
    return Mono.fromCompletionStage(client.deleteMessage(message)).then();
}
```

```
public Mono<Void> delete(Message message) {
    return Mono.fromCompletionStage(() -> client.deleteMessage(message)).then();
}
```

The `Mono.fromCompletionStage` documentation states

> Create a Mono, producing its value using the provided CompletionStage.

The lambda version states

> Create a Mono that wraps a lazily-supplied CompletionStage on subscription, emitting the value produced by the CompletionStage.

Now I am wondering whether my wrapper should use the non-lambda version or not. So far I see no reason to ever use the non-lambda version, since it can lead to very nasty side-effects. That means it would always start the `CompletableFuture` on assembly time, even if there's an error. For example:

```
.process(message).then(myWrapper.delete(message))
```

If delete uses the non-lambda version, it will delete the message even if process returns an error (since the future starts on assembly time). Whoever uses my wrapper can of course use `Mono.defer`, but if they forget that it will be very bad.

So when would I ever use the non-lambda version? What should a wrapper use?

Answer (score 0):

The code flow may not be as straightforward as the calling method that returns `CompletionStage`. Sometimes you can use `CompletableFuture` to return a response that will be processed later. For example, let's take a look at the case when you need to put all requests into a queue and process them one by one:

```java
public class App {
    private final Sinks.Many<Args> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
    private final Scheduler single = Schedulers.newSingle("my-processor");

    static class Args {
        String requestArg;
        CompletableFuture<String> responseFuture;

        public Args(String requestArg, CompletableFuture<String> responseFuture) {
            this.requestArg = requestArg;
            this.responseFuture = responseFuture;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var app = new App();
        app.initOnStartup();
        // some time later
        app.processRequest("hello").subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    public Mono<String> processRequest(String arg) {
        CompletableFuture<String> responseFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        sink.emitNext(new Args(arg, responseFuture), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.busyLooping(Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
        return Mono.fromCompletionStage(responseFuture); // or Mono.fromFuture()
    }

    public void initOnStartup() {
        sink.asFlux()
            .subscribeOn(single)
            .subscribe(args -> {
                String requestArg = args.requestArg;
                CompletableFuture<String> responseFuture = args.responseFuture;

                try {
                    // some request processing here
                    responseFuture.complete(requestArg + " response");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    responseFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

In this example method `processRequests` can be called simultaneously from different threads. But instead of processing the request immediately we just put it into the sink (queue) and then all actual processing will happen later in "my-processor" single thread. In this example we create `CompletableFuture` instance and wrap it into the `Mono` to give a response.